# Reset SharePoint online content types to default

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type

Firstly a confession, I knowingly added site columns to default content types. Our organisation is rebuilding its intranet and this seemed the easiest way to apply managed properties to a bunch of new sites.

Perhaps due to a page refresh issue, I accidentally added a site column twice. Before checking the implications, I deleted the duplicated site column not realising that it would orphan all instances of the column. I resolved to clean up manually but that's become a mess.

Without wrecking the whole site, I would like to return site content types to their default state. I've seen this answer https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/26225/94004, which looks promising. My question is what else happens when this is done? What gets reset, and what remains?

Thanks
Hans

Answer (score 0):

The **stsadm** commands do not work for SharePoint Online. You can use **SharePoint Online PowerShell** instead. (ps. I have tested with PnP PowerShell and it doesn’t work in this scenario.)

The script will deactivate and then reactivate the **CTypes Feature** in your site. **All** default site content types will be removed and then recreated, removing all columns and templates added manually.

Here is a sample script for your reference:

```
#Load SharePoint Online CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
 
#Function to Disable Feature in SharePoint Online
Function Disable-SPOFeature {
    param ($SiteCollURL,$UserName,$Password,$FeatureGuid)
    Try {    
        #Setup the context
        $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteCollURL)
        $Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Username, $Password)
        $Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials
        $Site=$Ctx.Site
 
        #Check the Feature Status
        $FeatureStatus =  $Site.Features.GetById($FeatureGuid)
        $FeatureStatus.Retrieve("DefinitionId")
        $Ctx.Load($FeatureStatus)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
 
        #Deactivate the feature if its enabled
        if($FeatureStatus.DefinitionId -ne $null){
            Write-Host "Disabling Feature $FeatureGuid..." -ForegroundColor Yellow
            $Site.Features.Remove($FeatureGuid, $true) | Out-Null
            $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
            Write-Host "Feature has been disabled on site $SiteCollURL!" -ForegroundColor Green
        }
        else{
            Write-host "Feature is Not Active on the Site collection!" -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    }
    Catch{
        write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red
    }
}
 
#Function to Enable Feature in SharePoint Online
Function Enable-SPOFeature{
    param ($SiteCollURL,$UserName,$Password,$FeatureGuid)
    Try{    
        #Setup the context
        $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteCollURL)
        $Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Username, $Password)
        $Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials
        $Site=$Ctx.Site
 
        #Check the Feature Status
        $FeatureStatus =  $Site.Features.GetById($FeatureGuid)
        $FeatureStatus.Retrieve("DefinitionId")
        $Ctx.Load($FeatureStatus)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
 
        #sharepoint online activate feature using powershell (if its not enabled already)
        if($FeatureStatus.DefinitionId -eq $null){
            Write-Host "Enabling Feature $FeatureGuid..." -ForegroundColor Yellow
            $Site.Features.Add($FeatureGuid, $true, [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FeatureDefinitionScope]::None) | Out-Null
            $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
            Write-Host "Feature Enabled on site $SiteCollURL!" -ForegroundColor Green
        }
        else{
            Write-host "Feature is Already Active on the Site collection!" -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    }
    Catch{
        write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red
    }
}
  
#Parameters to Activate Feature
$SiteCollURL = "<SiteURL>"
$UserName = "<AdminAccount>"
$Password = "<Password>"
$FeatureGuid = [System.Guid] ("695b6570-a48b-4a8e-8ea5-26ea7fc1d162") #CTypes Feature
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password –asplaintext –force 
 
#Disable Feature
Disable-SPOFeature -SiteCollURL $SiteCollURL -UserName $UserName -Password $SecurePassword -FeatureGuid $FeatureGuid

#Enable Feature
Enable-SPOFeature -SiteCollURL $SiteCollURL -UserName $UserName -Password $SecurePassword -FeatureGuid $FeatureGuid
```

References: [SharePoint Online: Deactivate Feature using PowerShell.](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/06/sharepoint-online-deactivate-feature-using-powershell.html) /
[SharePoint Online: Activate a Feature using PowerShell.](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/01/sharepoint-online-activate-feature-using-powershell.html)